# Alternative to window.crypto.signText in firefox 33

Tags: javascript, firefox

`window.crypto && window.crypto.signText`

Since firefox 33 , Mozilla no longer supports this feature.

However there's almost no information about the alternative to `window.crypto.signText` on the web or is there any at all?

Does anybody have a clue on this matter, appreciate the kind help?

Answer (score 6):

To enable signText temporary, you should type a new url in the address bar **about:config** and then right click -> New -> String.

Type **dom.unsafe_legacy_crypto.enabled** -> hit Enter -> select True.

Restart your Firefox browser.

Relevant issue is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083118.

Comment: This works, at least to do my work as quickly as possible. Anyway at least i know that there is a way to temporary enable this legacy functionality in order do my job and then disable it.

Comment: The dom.unsafe_legacy_crypto.enabled variable must be of type Boolean instead of String, i.e. the correct steps are "right click -> New -> Boolean".

Comment: The permanent solution now is [sighTextJS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/signtextjs/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal with my investigation on the matter:

Mozilla removed the old API in their version because of security issues and not being official standard - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/JavaScript_crypto

No back compatibility , nothing.

In future it is going to be replaced by the **Web Crypto API**

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302338(v=vs.85).aspx

  which is a total nonsense because it doesn't support certificates.

If you want to enable it in Firefox 33 type **about:config** as URL and then set:

`dom.webcrypto.enabled = true`

Finally here's more on the problem:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNzTCoxr2ek

So millions of users are left without the online signing with imported certificates under Firefox and there's nothing on the horizon coming for any of the browsers.

Comment: Seems they rolled it back to true in ffox 34

Comment: It is true in Firefox 37, but it doesn't seem to work at all. `window.crypto.signText` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Happily several people packaged the deprecated crypto.signCode() as firefox plugin. I personally use [signtextjs](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/signtextjs/?src=search) but there are few more to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/33/Site_Compatibility#Security

looks like the replacement is [Web Crypto API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).